# Creating new Transparent Stage on Event JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, transparent

I'm trying to create a new `Stage` when a button is pressed.

It works but the problem is that I'd like this `Stage` to be fully transparent and lets us see what's behind the screen.

**Code**

```
Dimension Sizescreen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

    //Main stage with option menu
    Pane window = new Pane();
    Scene scene = new Scene(window);
    stage.setTitle("Notification Extender");

    //Create the button SetLooker
    Button SetLooker = new Button("Set Looker");
    //Add a Event when pressed
    SetLooker.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

            //Create a sub-Stage
            Pane subwindow = new Pane();
            Scene subscene = new Scene(subwindow);
            Stage substage = new Stage();
            substage.setTitle("Notification Extender");

            //Set this subStage Transparent
            substage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            subscene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            substage.setWidth(Sizescreen.getWidth());
            substage.setHeight(Sizescreen.getHeight());
            substage.setX(0);
            substage.setY(0);

            //Create a a graphique element
            Rectangle redrec = new Rectangle(120,40,50,50);
            redrec.setStroke(Color.RED);
            redrec.setStrokeWidth(2);
            redrec.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);

            //Add the graphique element to the sub-stage
            subwindow.getChildren().add(redrec);

            //Show the sub-stage
            substage.setScene(subscene);
            substage.show();

        }
    });

    //Add the button to the main stage
    window.getChildren().add(SetLooker);

    //Show the main stage
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

The problem is that when I press the button it shows the stage but it's not transparent at all it's completely white.

I've also tried to change the main `Stage`, but I cannot change it once it has been shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to remove the background from the root of your new scene:

```
subwindow.setBackground(null);
```